# How to list the customers by last time they buy in Laravel Query

Tags: sql, laravel, join, left-join

I try to sort my customers list by their last order from table Orders.
But all is not working.

Please help me how to write Laravel 5.x Query.

Detail in the following link

Thank you very much!

This is my example picture:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `group by` and `order by` as follows:

```
select max(o.id) as order_id, c.customer_name
 from orders o join customer c on c.id = o.customer_id
group by c.customer_name, c.id
 order by max(o.id)
```